# Validate advanced post types in pods framework on save in backend

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, podscms

Which is the most correct way to validate inputs on new pod save from wordpress backend if the pod is an advanced post type with is own table?

I also want to return an error message if the inputs are not fixable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `pre_save` filter is our best bet.
http://pods.io/docs/code/filter-reference/pods_api_pre_save_pod_item/

Not sure yet how to return an error, but the `pods_error` method should handle the bits of the different circumstances.